# Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am new to coding. I am trying CRUD operation with express.js and MongoDB atlas for database on my project but when I am fetch for loading data for my client site server its error:

```
  var _this = _super.call(this, message) || this;
```

BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer

I am trying a lot but no result.

this is my code:

//this is client site code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const MeetingDetail = () => {
    const {meetingId} = useParams()
   
    const [meeting, setMeeting] = useState({})
    console.log(meeting)

    useEffect(() => {
        const url = `http://localhost:5000/meeting/${meetingId}`;
        console.log(url)
         fetch(url)
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then(data => setMeeting(data))
         
    },[])
    return (
        <div className='mx-auto w-75'>
            <h1>meetingID : {meeting.age}</h1>
            <Link to='/checkout'><button className='btn btn-primary mx-auto'>
                Process Checkout</button></Link>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MeetingDetail;
```

//this is server site code:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion, ObjectId } = require("mongodb");

const app = express();

// middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// from Mongodb
const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@cluster0.9nfwrgy.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1,
});
console.log("mongo connected");

async function run() {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    const meetingCollection = client.db("hotelRoom").collection("meeting");

    // create main link for component data
    app.get("/meeting", async (req, res) => {
      const query = {};
      const cursor = meetingCollection.find(query);
      const meetings = await cursor.toArray();
      res.send(meetings);
    });

    // create main link id for component data
    app.get("/meeting/:id", async (req, res) => {
      const id = req.params.id;
      const query = {_id: ObjectId(id) };
      const meeting = await meetingCollection.findOne(query);
      res.send(meeting);
    });
  }
  
  finally {

  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("starting server");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("CURD running", port);
});
```

Comment: Can you add `console.log(id)` right after `const id = req.params.id;` line?

Comment: With the use case you have, it's better to use `findById` instead of `findOne` with a query. As in, you can use, `meetingCollection.findById(id)` without using the `ObjectId` function.

Comment: const id = req.params.id;  id work when i am get http://localhost:5000/meeting/637257211d743f93d494519a, its work but why i am face this error???